# Storing a function in the value for a key within a hash

Tags: ruby

Right now, my ruby code looks like this:

```
case step
when 1
   # step_two_function
when 2
   # step_three_function
when 3
   # step_four_function
end
```

However, I'm wondering if I can store this in a hash to make things a little more simpler?

For example,

```
h = {
   1 => step_two_function,
   2 => step_three_function,
   3 => step_four_function,
}
```

And be able to just simply call the associated function with something like `h[step]`. It seems that, in Ruby, the function is executed at the same time as the hash being created, rather than only when the value of the key is called.

Is doing this possible and, if so, how?

In python, you would just simply do:

```
>>> def lies(altons_var):
...     print(altons_var)
... 
>>> a[1] = lies
>>> a[1]('print me please')
print me please
```

But this doesn't work in Ruby because the minute you call the function (whether directly or from a hash), it executes the function.

Comment: `step_two_function` is the method name so it will call the function while you declare the hash, you have to make that as a string and then you have to call like I have shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the send keyword

```
send h[step]
```

since you writing the method name directly in value part of the hash, the call is being made, but If you store the method names as a string and then if you call by send method as shown below, it would work.

```
def hi
  puts 'hi'
end

def hello
  puts 'hello'
end

h = {
    1 => 'hi',
    2 => 'hello',
}

send h[1]
```

Comment: I think the problem is that h will try to call all of its functions defined within it as soon as i finish defining the hash.

Comment: @LewlSauce That's because you are writing the function name directly and that will call the method, you have to make that as a string. See my example above.

Comment: @Rajagpalan I have various functions that are only to be called when a certain number is passed to the master function. It seems like the edited example is just simply storing a string as the values of the keys, but not actually calling the `hi` or `hello` function only when you `send h[1]` unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Yes, it will only call when the execution meets with `send h[1]`. That's what you want, right? you can pass any number inside `send h[2]` or `send h[2]`

Comment: I believe this example doesn't call the function at all. I don't see any reference between the `h` hash and any of the functions defined before it. The send h[1] command in this example will work regardless if the two functions above it exist or not.. I'm basically trying to store a call to the function as the variable, so that I can simply call the key and the associated function gets called.

Comment: If you don't define the `hi` then it would throw the error while you call `send h[1]` `undefined method `hi' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Gotcha. This actually did the trick. Much appreciated!!! Sorry I misunderstood at first. The what appeared to be strings are actually function names and send treats it as such. Very cool. Thanks again

Comment: There is no `send` keyword in Ruby. Are you talking about the `Object#send` method?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag  Oh sorry It's method.  And I wasn't knowing that send is for private method. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 6):

### Use a Proc or Lambda as Hash Values

The functionality you're after is likely to be best represented by a [Proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html) or [lambda](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda). These objects are closures that can be passed around and executed later. As a somewhat contrived example, consider the following code:

```rb
step = {
  1 => ->{p "foo"},
  2 => ->{p "bar"},
  3 => ->{p "baz"},
}

step.keys.map { |i| step[i].call }
#=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Each value in the hash contains a "stubby lambda" that you can invoke with the [Proc#call](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html#method-i-call) method. Using `step.keys.map` simply iterates over all the keys in your hash and calls each one in turn, but you can also call a single lambda from the hash with `step[1]` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

You can have method() here. For hash key, you can use any [symbol, string]

Ex:

```
    def foo(num)
          return num % 2
    end
    
    hash = { :func_name => method(:foo) }

hash[:func_name].call(10) #=> 0
```

You can also achieve it using Proc, Lambda also

Answer (score 1):

> Storing a function in the value for a key within a hash

Ruby doesn't have functions. What you have there, are *methods*, not functions.

There are multiple possibilities. You can store [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html)s in the [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html). In order to get a `Method` object, you can use the [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method:

```rb
h = {
  1 => method(:step_two_function),
  2 => method(:step_three_function),
  3 => method(:step_four_function),
}
```

`Method`s have a [`Method#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-call) method, so you can call them like this:

```rb
h[2].call
```

Or, by using the `call` syntactic sugar:

```rb
h[2].()
```

The second possibility is to use [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html)s instead of `Method`s:

```rb
h = {
  1 => -> {
    # contents of `step_two_function`
  },
  2 => -> {
    # contents of `step_three_function`
  },
  3 => -> {
    # contents of `step_four_function`
  },
}
```

Or, if that is not possible, you can call the methods from the `Proc`s:

```rb
h = {
   1 => -> { step_two_function },
   2 => -> { step_three_function },
   3 => -> { step_four_function },
}
```

`Proc`s also have a [`Proc#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-call) method, so you can call them the same way you can call `Method`s.

The last option would be to store the *names* of the methods in the `Hash`:

```rb
h = {
  1 => :step_two_function,
  2 => :step_three_function,
  3 => :step_four_function,
}
```

And then you can use [`Object#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```rb
public_send(h[2])
```

Please, don't use [`Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) unless you absolutely *have* to, i.e. if you absolutely *need* to circumvent [`Module#private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private) access restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the functions as Proc objects:

```
 h = {
     1 => :step_to_function.to_proc, 
     2 =>  proc { ... } 
     # etc.
 }
```

and then invoke it as

```
h[1].call
h[2].call
```

IMO, this is the most readable way, because we can see clearly what's going on, on the defining side and on the calling side. It also makes it easy to define a function at the place, without giving it a name, as I showed with `h[2]`.